# Coldfusion Looping over query

Tags: coldfusion

I have a query result something like

```
ID IDParent Name    Title
--------------------------------------
1  -1   Test1       Test1_Title 
2  -1       Test2       Test2_Title
3  -1       Test3       Test3_Title
4   2   SubTest2    SubTest2_Title
5   2   SubTest3    SubTest3_Title
6   2   SubTest4    SubTest4_Title
7   3   SubTest6    SubTest8_Title
8   3   SubTest8    SubTest10_Title
```

with menu and submenu options.I want to loop over the menu option where `IDParent` is -1 and after each menu Item where `IDParent` -1 I would like to loop its child items.

Does coldfusion provides such grouping when looping over queries?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's pretty easy with Query of Queries (QoQ) and a little recursion:

```
<!-- database query, sorted in the way you want to display the results -->
<cfquery name="Menu" datasource="#YourDSN#">
  SELECT   ID, IDParent, Name, Title
  FROM     Menu
  ORDER BY Name
</cfquery>

<!-- output menu -->
<cfset OutputQueryRecursive(Menu, -1)>

<!-- support function -->
<cffunction name="OutputQueryRecursive">
  <cfargument name="BaseQuery" type="query"   required="yes">
  <cfargument name="ParentId"  type="numeric" required="yes">

  <cfquery name="CurrLevel" dbtype="query">
    SELECT * FROM BaseQuery WHERE IDParent = #ParentId#
  </cfquery>

  <cfif CurrLevel.RecordCount gt 0>
    <ul>
      <cfoutput query="CurrLevel">
        <li id="menu_#ID#">
          <span title="#HTMLEditFormat(Title)#">#HTMLEditFormat(Name)#</span>
          <cfset OutputQueryRecursive(BaseQuery, ID)>
        </li>
      </cfouptut>
    </ul>
  </cfif>
</cffunction>
```

Answer (score 5):

CFOUTPUT supports query groupings as well.

```
<cfquery name="qGetTests" datasource="#DSN#">
  SELECT   ID, IDParent, Name, Title
  FROM     Menu
  ORDER BY IDParent, Name
</cfquery>

<cfoutput query="qGetTests" group="IDParent">
    #IDParent#<br />
    <cfoutput>
       #ID# #Name# #Title#<br />
    </cfoutput>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: how would you like the data to display? This should give you enough information to format the output the way you'd like it displayed

Answer (score 1):

If you have any control of the SQL generating that query result, you could consider getting the DB to get you the data back in the right format in the first place. Approaches for Oracle and SQL server are covered [here](http://dbbest.net/blog/?p=44) and there's some options for mySQL [here](http://www.slideshare.net/billkarwin/models-for-hierarchical-data)

If your menu data is always going to be small, then there'll be no problem with Tomalak's solution, but if you're ever going to have large numbers of menu items then I'd test that it still performs ok.

Comment: If there are many, deeply nested menu options, I'd use one loop to build an index (a Struct) that can organizes items by Parent ID and a second loop that builds the menu using that index instead of query of queries. This would be plenty fast without the need to alter the DB structure.

Answer (score 0):

consider `qTestQuery` contains the values

```
<cfset qTestQuery1 = qTestQuery>
<cfloop query="qTestQuery">
    <cfif qTestQuery.IDParent eq -1>
        <span class="main-menu">#qTestQuery.name#</span>
    </cfif>
    <cfset local.parentId = qTestQuery.IDParent>
    <cfloop query="qTestQuery1">
         <cfif qTestQuery1.IDParent eq local.parentId>
              <span class="sub-menu">#qTestQuery1.name#</span>
         </cfif>
    </cfloop>
</cfloop>
```